# Issue downloading Revtex using Texstudio and miktex

Tags: pdftex, errors, texstudio, revtex

I am using TeXstudio as my editor, but am having trubles with the following document:

```
\documentclass[aip]{revtex4-1}
\begin{document}
    test
\end{document}
```

The MikTex package manager tries to install the required revtex files to my computer but ends up crashing, with the following error message:

> Sorry, but pdflatex.exe did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again

**Any advice on what to do next to get the file to work is appreciated!**  
 
The log file is as follows:
2021-11-12 14:09:59,364-0500 INFO  pdflatex - installing package revtex triggered by tex/latex/revtex\revtex4-1.cls
2021-11-12 14:10:01,866-0500 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: starting package maintenance...
2021-11-12 14:10:01,866-0500 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: installation directory: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9"
2021-11-12 14:10:01,866-0500 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: package repository: https://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
2021-11-12 14:10:02,258-0500 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: package repository digest: e2d72deecea829ce48d0b18aa9631711
2021-11-12 14:10:03,233-0500 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: going to download 4751960 bytes
2021-11-12 14:10:03,233-0500 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: going to install 63 file(s) (1 package(s))
2021-11-12 14:10:03,906-0500 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: downloading  https://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/revtex.tar.lzma...
2021-11-12 14:10:05,035-0500 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: 4.75 MB, 34.09 Mbit/s
2021-11-12 14:10:05,081-0500 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: extracting files from revtex.tar.lzma...
2021-11-12 14:10:08,659-0500 FATAL pdflatex - The installed file does not exist.
2021-11-12 14:10:08,659-0500 FATAL pdflatex - Info: fileName="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX  2.9\tex/latex/revtex\revtex4-1.cls"
2021-11-12 14:10:08,659-0500 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\findfile.cpp
2021-11-12 14:10:08,659-0500 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 59
2021-11-12 14:10:08,659-0500 INFO  pdflatex - finishing with exit code 1

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! As far as I know `revtex4-1` is outdated, the current version is `revtex4-2` ...

Comment: I ran the file with revtex 4-2 instead, and it works! I still may want to use revtex 4-1 for some compatibility issues, but I think this is good enough for now.

Comment: The differences between `revtex4-1` and `revtex4-2` are quite minimal, so for normal documents there should be no compatibility issues at all.